# Delphi Tokyo exception prevents setting function result

Tags: delphi, exception

Found that exception handling in Delphi Tokyo behaves a little different than in previous Delphi versions.

```
function FuncTest: integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
  try
    raise Exception.Create('Error Message');
  finally
    Result := 2;
  end;
end;

function Test:integer;
begin
  Result:=0;
  try
    Result:=FuncTest;
  finally
    ShowMessage(Result.ToString);
  end;
end;
```

In earlier Delphi versions the message box shows here "2", Tokyo - "0".
Is this a Tokyo bug or the exceptions should not be handled like this?

Comment: I ran the same code in Delphi 7, and it shows "0".  (I had to change ToString to IntToStr).   In what versions of Delphi do you see "2"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Tokyo behaviour is correct. A function that raises an exception does not return a value. You have hitherto been relying on implementation detail.

Consider this code:

```
Result:=FuncTest;
```

This executes as follows:

1. `FuncTest` is called.
2. `Result` is assigned.

Now, because step 1 raises an exception, step 2 does not execute.

If anything, I would say that the behaviour you report from earlier versions is dubious. In this function:

```
function Test:integer;
begin
  Result:=0;
  try
    Result:=FuncTest;
  finally
    ShowMessage(Result.ToString);
  end;
end;
```

The statement `Result:=FuncTest` raises an exception and so `Result` should not be modified by that statement. Another way to think of it is that the function is called but the assignment is not executed.

---

One of the problems with the Delphi ABI is that function return values are sometimes implemented as implicit `var` parameters. Which means that the assignment may or may not happen. To demonstrate:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TRec1 = record
    X1: NativeInt;
  end;

  TRec2 = record
    X1: NativeInt;
    X2: NativeInt;
  end;

function GetRec1: TRec1;
begin
  Result.X1 := 1;
  raise Exception.Create('');
end;

function GetRec2: TRec2;
begin
  Result.X1 := 1;
  raise Exception.Create('');
end;

procedure Main;
var
  Rec1: TRec1;
  Rec2: TRec2;
begin
  Rec1 := Default(TRec1);
  Writeln(Rec1.X1);
  try
    Rec1 := GetRec1;
  except
  end;
  Writeln(Rec1.X1);

  Rec2 := Default(TRec2);
  Writeln(Rec2.X1);
  try
    Rec2 := GetRec2;
  except
  end;
  Writeln(Rec2.X1);
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

This outputs:

```
0
0
0
1
```

Which is rather disappointing. It should not be possible to modify the caller's variable, but the use of an implicit `var` parameter rather than a value return allows this leakage. In my view this is a serious flaw in the design of the Delphi ABI, a flaw that you will not find in most other languages.

---

In your code, there is no `var` parameter because the return type is transferred in a register. In which case any Delphi version that outputs `2` is broken.

Fundamentally though, your code is mistaken in its expectations. If a function raises an exception then you must assume that the return value is ill-defined.

Finally, your code outputs `0` in XE3 and XE7, so I wonder how far back you need to go to see a value of `2`.

Comment: I have no earlier Delphi version, but I think it is XE2 where x64 compiler was introduced. A have a code that relied on the fact that the FuncTest returns either 1 (without try block) or 2. Ok I got it, no more functions raising exceptions, only procedures.

Comment: It's fine for a function to raise exceptions. What's wrong is to expect a value to be returned in that case. In this case, because the return type fits in a register, the ABI is fine, no `var` param issues. But yes, XE2 64 bit had a good few issues.

Comment: You mean that if the function returned e,g, a record then there would be no problem?

Comment: I would not say "no problem", because your code is semantically wrong, full stop. But what I mean is that the actually observed behaviour might be different, but only because of implementation details that you should not rely on.

Comment: Ok, no more functions and implicit vars in the code that might raise an exception.

Comment: I wouldn't say that either.

Comment: It's a stronger statement than required but it guarantees lack of exception handling problems

Comment: @Molochnik if a function raises an exception, just don't make *any* assumptions about the validity of its return value. Period. That applies to ALL Delphi versions. If you have code that relies on a return value even if an exception is raised, then simply make sure to explicitly assign a value to the variable that the return value *would have* been assigned to had an exception not is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
    function FuncTest: integer;
    begin
      Result := 1;
      try
        try
          raise Exception.Create('Error Message');
        except
          { do nothing }
        end
      finally
        Result := 2;
      end;
    end;
```

Don't think that "finally" handles an exception locally, rather than "returning an exception".  To handle it locally requires a LOCAL try-except clause.